# overflow hidden on the bottom not on the top

Tags: css, react-native

I have  component that contains an Image and I just can't seem to style it the way as in the photo attached
can someone help please the green frame with the white background is the image background and the guys picture is the image[image: attached photo]

[image: player]
[image: frame]

Comment: can you replicate the same in exposnack, will sort it out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use overflow props. for the image(guys picture) use this style =>
{{position:'absolute, top:-10}}

Comment: I did try that <ImageBackground
          source={require('../assets/frame.png')}
          style={{
            height: 70,
            width: 70,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
          }}
        >
          <Image
            source={{ uri: props?.player_image }}
            style={{
              height: '100%',
              width: '70%',
              position: 'absolute',
              top: -10
            }}
          />
        </ImageBackground>
but the outcome is not making sense the image is getting everywhere

Comment: share your images and i fix it for you

Comment: I just edited the question to include the images

Comment: your player image has background color, you should pick a image with transparent background color